# When rendering cube with triangle strip, unintended planes are formed

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

After generating a cube with triangle strips, odd deformities, in the form of planes, are created:
[image: example]
My triangle strip measurements come from this question: [Cube using single GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375338/cube-using-single-gl-triangle-strip)

Here is my `drawCube` function:

```py
def drawRec():
    glColor3f(255, 0, 0)
    cubePoints = [
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,     # Front-top-left
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,      # Front-top-right
        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,    # Front-bottom-left
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,     # Front-bottom-right
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,    # Back-bottom-right
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,      # Front-top-right
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,     # Back-top-right
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,     # Front-top-left
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,    # Back-top-left
        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,    # Front-bottom-left
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,   # Back-bottom-left
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,    # Back-bottom-right
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,    # Back-top-left
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0      # Back-top-right
        ]
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, cubePoints)
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 52)
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
```

Is there any way I can remove these planes? What is going on here?

Comment: Third parameter of the `glDrawArrays` is `count`, why do you pass 52? The `cubePoints` has 14 vertices.

Comment: THANK YOU. That fixed it. I defined 52 because I was not able to put it into array format, so I assumed it would require individual values.